# laravel iteration adding value to the next user if the user rank does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have function that will insert an amount to the users up to the last rank based on `parent_id`. I can get the `parent_id` up to the last rank, its fine and I'm using an `iteration` or something like `recursion`. But I can't add the amount if the user rank is not present.

The expected result of the function is to insert an amount to each `User Rank`, **but** if the iteration/recursion didn't find a user with the `rank` the amount to be inserted to him will be added on the next `user rank`.

The function will trigger once a user bought a `product`, so whoever user buy a product it will get his `parent_id` and insert the `amount` assigned to that rank.

I have a list of rank `in order` who will receive the amount.

```
Basic - 50
Junior - 100
Premium - 150
Advanced - 200
Senior - 250
```

Database:

```
+------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  id  |  username  |  parent_id  |   rank     |
+------+------------+-------------+------------+
|  1   |   john     |    NULL     |  Senior    |
|  2   |   jane     |    1        |  Advanced  |
|  3   |   josh     |    2        |  Premium   |
|  4   |   joey     |    3        |  Junior    |
|  5   |   jade     |    4        |  Basic     |
------------------------------------------------
```

For example:

`Jade` bought an item, once the order is success I will call the function to insert the `earnings`.

In this scenario `Joey, Josh, Jane and John` will received their earnings based on the corresponding amount of their `rank`.

This is working fine in this scenario because all the ranks are present, but my problem is to add the `amount` set to `rank` if the user is not in the `iteration`,

For example, `Joey` with the `rank - Junior` is not in the iteration, the amount designated to him which is `100` will be added on the next `rank` which is the `Premium`, and proceed the earnings insertion on the next ranks, but prevent adding the `amount` to them, because the amount `should only be added` to the next rank if the user with that rank is not present in the iteration.

```
// successfully bought a product and saved to database

$user_id = 5; // jade
$parent_id = 4;
    
// call the function to insert the earnings

self::insertEarnings($user_id,$parent_id);
```

This is the function that will insert the earnings:

```
private function insertEarnings($user_id,$parent_id) {

    if ($parent_id > 0) {
        
        $user_parent = $parent_id;
        
        $has_parent = true;
        
        // start iteration
        while($has_parent == true){
            
            $account = User::where('id',$user_parent)->first();
            
            $amount = 0;

            if ($account->rank == "Junior" ) {
                
                $amount = 100;
                    
            } elseif ($account->rank == "Premium") {

                $amount = 150;

            } elseif ($account->rank == "Advanced") {

                $amount = 200;
                
            } elseif ($account->rank == "Senior") {

                $amount = 250;
                
                // set to false to stop the iteration
                $has_parent = false;
            }

            $earnings = new Earnings;
            $earnings->user_id = $account->id;
            $earnings->amount = $amount;
            $earnings->save();
                    
            $next_parent = User::where('id',$user_parent)->first();
            $user_parent = $next_parent->parent_id;

            if($user_parent == 0){
                $has_parent = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The earnings was inserted to Joey, Josh, Jane and John because they are all present in the iteration, the real question is, how to insert the amount assigned to the rank if he is not present in the iteration.

EDIT:

Please someone help me? I can't really make a solution for this code. Adding the amount to the next user rank if the rank is not found in the iteration/loop.

Jade order a product, let's assume it is successful. Now I will trigger the `insertEarnings` function.
I will get his `parent_id` which is `Joey`,

`Joey` will get an amount of `100`, also `Josh, Jane and John` they will get an amount according to their rank.

The main problem is what if someone is `NOT` in the iteration/loop, the amount for that `rank` whatever that rank is will be **added** to the next rank.

Comment: what is `iteration` here ? can't see any loop here

Comment: you can see while there

Comment: I am asking for clarification. 
1. Has Joey been removed from the database? 
2. Is Joey's earning amount supposed to now go to Josh?
3. In this scenario Josh would be receiving 150 because he is Premium, and 100 because Joey is Junior but has been removed from the database. Is this what we are trying to achieve?

Comment: yes @AndrewEarls you got that.

Answer (score 3):

Reading the comments, I think your problem now is how to sum up the amount if certain user rank is not exist right?

I have a logic to iterate the ranks by using this code.

```
public function insertEarnings()
{
    // Rank Map
    $ranks  = [[
        'name' => 'Basic',
        'point' => 50,
    ], [
        'name' => 'Junior',
        'point' => 100,
    ], [
        'name' => 'Premium',
        'point' => 150,
    ], [
        'name' => 'Advanced',
        'point' => 200,
    ], [
        'name' => 'Senior',
        'point' => 250,
    ]];

    // Find Current Rank & Init Others
    $current = array_search($this->rank, array_column($ranks, 'name'));
    $rank    = null;
    $user    = null;
    $amount  = 0;

    // Loop while next rank still exist
    while (array_key_exists($current + 1, $ranks)) {
        // Find next rank, user within that rank, and sum up the amount.
        $rank   = $ranks[$current + 1];
        $user   = User::where('rank', $rank['name'])->first();
        $amount += $rank['point'];

        // Add current to iterate trough ranks
        $current++;

        // If user is found save the earning and restart the amount to 0
        if(!is_null($user)){
            $earnings = new Earning;
            $earnings->user_id = $user->id;
            $earnings->amount = $amount;
            $earnings->save();

            $amount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And using that code I able to make the earnings like in the table bellow by calling

> $user->insertEarnings() // jane

```
+------+--------+----------+
|  id  |  name  |  amount  | 
+------+--------+----------+
|  1   |  josh  |  250     |
|  2   |  jane  |  200     |
|  3   |  john  |  250     |
----------------------------
```

Is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: thank you. It seems that you understand what I'm trying to achieve and your answer is pretty close. But it seems like it didn't get the `parent_id` of the user in the iteration. Because the insertion will base on the `parent_id` and it's `rank`.

Comment: sure. if you need the `parent_id` of the current user to be inserted in `Earning` model, just add `$earnings->parent_id = $user->parent_id;` after you assign the `$earnings->amount = $amount;` line. Do the same thing for the `rank` value to insert it too.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure I did understand what you are trying to do here but from what I understood, you have a problem if the *user who bought the item* is not at the bottom of your list (in your example `Jade` with `id=5`).

So, if e.g. `Josh` would buy the item, `Joey` and `Jade` would miss out their earnings since they appear lower down in the database. You start your loop with Josh’s *parent ID* at `parent_id=2` and set the pointers to the next entry further up in the database (the logic in your code is really confusing here and could do with some cleanup or even a reconsideration).

Anyway, if you still want to consider all other candidates - in our example `John`, `Jane`, `Joey` and `Jade` - you need to fetch the **last database entry** first and start your loop

```
private function insertEarnings($user_id, $parent_id) {

  $mumEntries = User::where('id')->last() // not sure if this is the right syntax but you get the point! You want the highest possible user ID in the DB.

  for ( $i=$numEntries; $i>=0; $i—- ) {
    
    if ( $i !== $user_id ) { // skip the user who has purchased an item
      $user = User::where(‘id’, $i) // again, only if this means ‘get user with id=$i’
      
      // ... do logic with $amount
      
      $earnings = new Earnings;
      $earnings->user_id = $i;
      $earnings->amount = $amount;
      $earnings->save();
    }
  }
}
```

I don’t have the syntax for Laravel Database Objects in mind right now but I hope this helps.

Comment: you have a problem if the user who bought the item is not at the bottom of your list (in your example Jade with id=5).

@florian, I have a problem not with the user who bought, but the parent_id's beyond him

Comment: Yes, but the `parent_id`’s are obsolete, since you only need them to “bubble up” in your DB schema. If not I don’t know why you would need them for.

Comment: i need them for referrals.

Comment: the code i posted is working fine, but the main problem is, what if a user with rank of for example. rank `Premium` the amount that should be inserted to him, will be added to the next user rank which is `Advanced`

Comment: In your example, you start with eg `parent_id=4`. Then you “loop through” the DB objects by going to the next DB entry. Your `account` object is the same as the `next_parent` object and you never make use of `user_id` in `insert_earnings`.

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't use the `$user_id` in that example. but it has something to do, which is not included there.

Comment: do you have any idea how to add the `amount` to the next `parent user`? if someone is not in the iteration.

Comment: @KonjeshEsbrading yes, because you generate your `account` objects by checking where `id = parent_id`. So, if you start with `parent_id = 2` you get the user with `id = 2` in your account object. Which is obviously the next one up in the list.

Comment: what. i didn't understand.

Comment: That was supposed to answer a post further up... in my example you would add the amounts to ALL users except the one who purchased the item.

Comment: i mean. the posted code above is working fine. the only problem is adding the amount to the parent if the user with the rank in the conidiotn in the loop is not present

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224187/discussion-between-florian-ragossnig-and-konjesh-esbrading).

Answer (score 2):

I spent 30 minutes trying to understand what you want, but heres an improved and cleaner function for you to use :

```
    public function insertEarnings($user_id) {
        $ranks = [
            'Basic' => 50,
            'Junior' => 100,
            'Premium' => 150,
            'Advanced' => 200,
            'Senior' => 250
        ];

        $user = User::find($user_id);
        if($user) {
            //create earning for current user
            if(array_key_exists($user->rank, $ranks)) {
                $earnings = new Earnings();
                $earnings->user_id = $user->id;
                $earnings->amount  = $ranks[$user->rank];
                $earnings->save();
            }

            if($user->parent_id != null) {
                $this->insertEarnings($user->parent_id);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: looking into this, i think this is not what i wanted to do. it is not adding the amount to the next rank.

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve what you are trying to do you will need to edit how users are removed from the database.

Here is a link to the documentation for soft deleting. This can be applied to existing database structures with a new migration. Please test before pushing to production. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#soft-deleting

Once we have soft deletes in place we can modify the insert earnings function.

```
// passed in the id of user that made a purchase
private function insertEarnings($user_id) {

$user = User::where('id',$user_id)->first();

if ($user->parent_id > 0) {
    
    $next_parent_id = $user->parent_id;
    
    $has_parent = true;

    $amount = 0;
    
    // start iteration
    while($has_parent === true){
        
        $parent = User::withTrashed()->where('id',$next_parent_id)->first();

        if ($parent->rank == "Junior" ) {
            
            $amount += 100;
                
        } elseif ($parent->rank == "Premium") {

            $amount += 150;

        } elseif ($parent->rank == "Advanced") {

            $amount += 200;
            
        } elseif ($parent->rank == "Senior") {

            $amount += 250;
            
            // set to false to stop the iteration
            $has_parent = false;
        }

        if (!$parent->trashed()) {

            $earnings = new Earnings;
            $earnings->user_id = $parent->id;
            $earnings->amount = $amount;
            $earnings->save();

            $amount = 0;
        }
                
        $next_parent_id = $parent->parent_id;

        if($user_parent_id === 0){
            $has_parent = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I have cleaned up your original function a little, but I would refer to Konjesh Esbrading for a cleaner example. An explanation of what I have done. If the parent has been soft deleted from the database they will not get the earnings and the `$amount` will not be reset to `0`. The next availible parent will then get both amounts.

Because of the iteration loop this may take a while on larger databases which could cause timeout errors. In order to prevent that from happening I would like to suggest you look into using queues and jobs:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues

Comment: thank you for your answer @Andrew, I mean not soft deleted, literally didnt exists in the table

Comment: okay. Does the table have multiple users per rank or is it only one person per rank?

Comment: one person per rank, only one rank in one user

Comment: @AndrewEarls , do you have an update on your answer? looking into it

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking for a model's existence before accessing properties. maybe that's a problem.

```
private function insertEarnings($user_id,$parent_id) {

    if ($parent = User::find($parent_id)) {
        
        $has_parent = false;
        // start iteration
        while($has_parent){
            $amount = 0;
            if ($parent->rank === "Junior" ) {
                $amount = 100;
            } elseif ($parent->rank === "Premium") {
                $amount = 150;
            } elseif ($parent->rank === "Advanced") {
                $amount = 200;
            } elseif ($parent->rank == "Senior") {
                $amount = 250;
                // set to false to stop the iteration
                $has_parent = false;
            }

            $earning = Earnings::create([
                'user_id' => $parent->id,
                'amount'  => $amount,
            ]);

            if($parent->parent()->exists()){ // define hasOne() relation in model
                $parent = $parent->parent;
            } else {
                $has_parent = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```